# Using a SQL Server stored procedure fails in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, odbc

Struggling to access a SQL Server stored procedure from VB.net:

```
DECLARE @R INT
DECLARE @trm VARCHAR(255)
SET @trm = 'PartNumber'

EXECUTE @R = [dbo].[usp_CannedGlobalSearch] @trm
```

This SQL statement returns 12 columns in SQL Server Management Studio. Works great.

```vb
Dim StoredConn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection(SQLRdrConnectString)
Dim StoredCommand As New OdbcCommand
("CALL usp_CannedGlobalSearch (?)", StoredConn)
StoredCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
StoredCommand.CommandText = "{? = CALL usp_CannedGlobalSearch(?)}"
StoredCommand.Parameters.Add("@RC", OdbcType.Int)  'this is the result
StoredCommand.Parameters.Add("@trm", OdbcType.VarChar)   'sending a search string
StoredCommand.Parameters("@term").Value = "PartNumber"
StoredConn.Open()
Dim TestInt As Integer = StoredCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Runtime results:

> ERROR [HY105] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Parameter Type.

Comment: Why are you using ODBC instead of SqlClient? As a managed provider, SqlClient will be faster. Try specifying `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` for the return code parameter.

Comment: I concur. If you use `SqlClient` then you set the `CommandText` to the sproc name only. Generally speaking, the only good reason to use ODBC with SQL Server is if you want to be able to support other ODBC data sources using the same code. If this is just for SQL Server, `SqlClient` is almost certainly a better option.

Comment: By the way, why are you setting the `CommandText` via the constructor and then again explicitly?

Comment: You `.Add("@trm"` but then set `("@term").Value`, which isn't going to work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you would call a stored procedure in SQL Server from VB.NET with the parameter you showed:

```
Dim testInt As Integer = -1

Using conn As New SqlConnection(SQLRdrConnectString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_CannedGlobalSearch", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {
                           .ParameterName = "@trm",
                           .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                           .Size = 255,
                           .Value = "PartNumber"})

        conn.Open()
        Dim res As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        If res IsNot Nothing Then
            testInt = Convert.ToInt32(res)
        End If

    End Using
End Using
```

The part with `Dim res As Object...` is to take account of nothing at all being returned, not even NULL and the value of `testInt` would be -1 so you could check for that. If the stored procedure *always* returns an integer then it could be replaced with just one line:

```
testInt = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```